# How to trigger an event when django foreignkey is modified

Tags: django

I want to update fields in django admin site following the modification by the user of a given foreignkey field. I seek a way to trigger the event straight after foreignkey modification; ***not before/after save***.

I looked for the creation of a custom signal through sender/receiver. Also I tried to find a similar signal as the m2m_changed. Perhaps one of these path could be the solution.

```py
class Variety(models.Model):
    specific_name = models.ForeignKey(CatalogList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def update_other_field(self):
        #DO SOMETHING EACH TIME specific_name IS MODIFIED
```

Is there a way to trigger an event directly after a foreignkey is modified?

Comment: You want to call a method when the value of the foreign key has been changed on the model but not saved to the database?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to call this method while saving modifications to an instance of your model. If that is the case then you __have__ to call this method either pre or post save, there is no other time it can be called?

Comment: So when do you want to trigger it? When the user changes the drop down element on the admin page itself?

Comment: We cannot trigger an event at a modification stage in django context (ie. display in admin site)? (I means not a modification in database because in this case I understand it will make sense only at pre/post save.) The purpose of my question is to be able to pre-format all fields in the admin site based on the selection made by the user in a specific foreignkey field. Thus if the user changes the selection of the foreignkey (not considering yet to save)  all others fields will be update following the drafted method above (update_other_field).

Comment: exact, I want to trigger it when the user changes the drop down element on the admin page itself

Comment: You'll need to use javascript for that

Comment: Thanks Iain, I'll pursue a solution along that path. However, I'm surprised that nothing can be done directly in django since there is the trigger mechanic implemented for save and I thought connect and signal concept were designed to implement such custom trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `save` method of "parent" model :

```
class CatalogList(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call normal save method

        # Then do what you want with variety_set reverse relation
```